# Can anyone tell me what the mistake is in the following osql syntax?

Tags: sql-server

```
osql -U sa -d master -i ConnectInternal.sql -U sa -P ""
```

I need to login with `sa` account with blank password. But it returns an error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Your `sa` account has a blank password!?!??!?! You **do know** just how dangerous and risky that is, don't you??? .....

Comment: Also: which **version** of SQL Server are you using?? With SQL Server 2005 and newer, you should really switch to the [`SQLCMD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) tool and toss `osql` ....

Comment: Check this on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213088(v=sql.80).aspx I didn't see `-d` option there

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`SQLCMD` documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), if you have a "blank" password, just specify `-P` at the end of your command and nothing after that - so try:

```
sqlcmd -d master -i ConnectInternal.sql -U sa -P
```

Also: you're not specifying any **server** here...... you probably need to add `-S yourserver` to the command line, too!

Comment: osql  -U sa -d master -i ConnectInternal.sql -U sa -P -S WIN-L7IUL0CD1B0\sa

i changed but still getting same error

Comment: @chida: you need to put the `-P` **at the end** of your command!